# Bash doesn't print color when using echo -e

Tags: bash

I'm having the following code to print the message in green color. However, a ^[ was printed instead.

```
[/home/nghiatran/script] >cat test_color_msg.sh
#!/bin/bash

function main {
    local GREEN="\033[01;32m"
    local NONE="\033[00m"

    echo -e "${GREEN}hello world${NONE}"
}

main

[/home/nghiatran/script] >./test_color_msg.sh
^[[01;32mhello world^[[00m
[/home/nghiatran/script] >
```

Please help me to know the reason why it wasn't green.

Comment: What ```echo $TERM``` shows?

Comment: value of $TERM is xterm

Comment: Do you 'ssh' into your Linux, or some other remoting ?

Comment: I used mobaxterm from my laptop and ssh to this machine.

Comment: I guess it is worth to give it a try using another terminal emulator, like [PuTTY](https://putty.org/).

Comment: What is the 'local' terminal setting in MobaXterm. MobaXterm support VT100, VT220, VT900 and xterm. The TERM must match the local setting  - Consider fixing the local session setting, or fix XTERM).

Comment: It's xterm and same as with my remote machine.

Comment: Can you share output of './test_color_msg.sh | hexdump' ? Also, what version of BASH do you use ?